# Is it possible to specify some value/text in a specific number of column cells depending on the input of another cell?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

If I have a cell in which the input has to be a number, is it possible to insert some specific text in a number of consecutive columned cells somewhere else in the sheet.

I'm not sure whether this is done with a formula or another built in function.

As an example, say I have a cell `E4`. 

If I enter the number 3 in `E4`, the cells `F1`,`F2`,`F3` show some text. If I change the number in `E4` to 6 then cells `F1-F6` now display some text.

Is this at all remotely possible?

I know I would be able to to do this with multiple `IF-THEN-ELSE`, but is there a more efficient method?

Answer (score 0):

I'll presume you are in a google-spreeadsheet and not in an excel (your tags are confusing btw)

I would do that using a hidden cell to minimize the numbers of IF statements.

Saying `E4` is your numeric cell, put only one `IF` in `F4` like

`IF(E4=1;"text text2";IF(E4=2;"othertext othertext2 othertex3"; IFS...  ))`

So you will have the whole texts in a unique cell (I separated then by spaces but if you have spaces in your text just use a more convenient character).
Then you can do a `SPLIT` on `G4` like

`=SPLIT(F4;" ")` 
(or split on the character you have used).

And it will separate your data in 1, 2, 6, or how many rows you'll need for your data without having to make if statements for each row.